# Disable Hyperlink & convert the link to text in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, hyperlink

Posting it again, but with more information.
I want to disable Hyperlink and convert the link to text in SharePoint.

I`m using Jquery and below is the code. the code works fine for the first time, but if you click on any other section wherein we want the link to work and comeback to the page. Then the link that was disabled via Jquery even start functioning again.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script>

$(function() {

$('.ms-vb').removeAttr("href");
// disable all links in a document
$('a').removeAttr("href"); 

});

</script>
```

Any suggestion on how the link doesn't function even if the page is refreshed or so.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put your code inside document.ready() function and check.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    **--- Your code here**

});
```

Comment: still the same. works for the first time after adding the code in content editor. But later it doesn't.

Comment: @Jason I could disable all the links on my page using below code:

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ms-vb').removeAttr("href");
// disable all links in a document
$('a').removeAttr("href"); 
});
</script>`

Can you check browser console for any JS errors from browser developer tools when you come back to page second time. Use F12 for developer tools to appear -> Console

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the MDS (Minimal Download Strategy) Feature is enabled which makes only changed content on the page update.

1. Disable the MDS feature
   or
2. Write extra code to execute your JS always

2 Takes some serious programming, there is not much MDS information out there, besides, MDS has no future, it looks like Microsoft already disabled it on Office365 sometime in the past weeks

Comment: disabling MDS did helped. Now if a page is started fresh then it wont the javascripts works. However, if the user clicked on links part of another webpart and comeback by clicking back. The disabled links start working again. I identified for the URL at the end when it has "?PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage"  then the blocked links even start working. Any suggestion what I should add so it doesn't allows the link to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">

$(window).load(function(){your code here...});

</script>
```

This will upload your code only when all your DOM has loaded